# How to decouple objects in MVC Web API service and apps which uses it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I've just finished working on a MVC web api service, which only purpose is to show some data from Microsft Analysis Cube, and return JSON objects.

So lets say i have an object  which is loaded from cube and returned from service as JSON:

```
public class Person{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public double Balance {get;set;}
}
```

Now on my MVC APP which makes request to service i create this exact same class, so i can desirealize from JSON. As you can see if Person object will be extended with LastName atribute, then i have to add exact same attribute in the app too. Are there any architecturs / patterns to avoid creating exact same class/object on both App and Webservice?

Maybe create a separate library which contains all the nessesary objects, and parse it in as dll into webservice and app? or are there any other way?

Comment: you could do what you are saying by making a common entity assembly and referencing it however the problem will be maintenance - for instance, a certain tier may require something different than another tier and could cause conflicts or be incompatible. Best thing is to have separate models i.e have ViewModels for the UI and have an entity type to map to and from at the backend. only give the necessary data required

Comment: @Ahmedilyas but the problem will still presist? entitys and models in webservice should still be out of sync if model on webservice changes?

Comment: Why you need to create named object at API project. You can simply create anonymous type objects, this way you will only need to maintain models at mvc application (when de-serialize)

Comment: @Timsen - correct but it is best practice otherwise you are going to be running into the issue of continuously extending a model, exposing more information that the specific tier requires and possibly adding dependencies when it is completely unnecessary. you are then making a tight coupled application rather than a loosely coupled app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ahmed is right. You should create separate models or view models to expose certain data per tier. There are security implications when you overpost data to certain endpoints. The data may be highly confidential like a salary, for example, and show up in the wrong places. You may use an AutoMapper to map data between tiers. Looks like it at least addresses the problem you are trying to solve:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper